# Redshift external catalog error when copying parquet from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, parquet, spark-redshift

I am trying to copy Google Analytics data into redshift via parquet format. When I limit the columns to a few select fields, I am able to copy the data. But on including few specific columns I get an error:

```
ERROR: External Catalog Error. Detail: ----------------------------------------------- error: External Catalog Error. code: 16000 context: Unsupported column type found for column: 6. Remove the column from the projection to continue. query: 18669834 location: s3_request_builder.cpp:2070 process: padbmaster [pid=23607] -----------------------------------------------
```

I know the issue is most probably with the data, but I am not sure how can I debug as this error is not helpful in anyway. I have tried changing data types of the columns to super, but without any success. I am not using redshift spectrum here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. In the error message it says `Unsupported column type found for column: 6`. Redshift column ordinality starts from 0. I was counting columns from 1, instead of 0 (my mistake). So this means issue was with column 6 (which I was reading as column 7), which was a `string` or `varchar` column in my case. I created a table with just this column and tried uploading data in just this column. Then I got

```
redshift_connector.error.ProgrammingError: {'S': 'ERROR', 'C': 'XX000', 'M': 'Spectrum Scan Error', 'D': '\n  -----------------------------------------------\n  error:  Spectrum Scan Error\n  code:      15001\n  context:   The length of the data column display_name is longer than the length defined in the table. Table: 256, Data: 1020
```

Recreating the column with `varchar(max)` for those columns solved the issue

Comment: I understand what you mean, but mixing terminology is going to break you, and others you communicate with.  Most indexes in computing are 0 based, so this really ***is*** Column 6.  Usinging a different base, because you personally like it, is just going to lead to confusion.  Adopt the standard, it's always the best way forward.

Comment: Agreed @MatBailie, edited my answer reflecting your suggestions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have semistructured data in your parquet (like an array).

In this case, you can have a look at this page at the very bottom https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/ingest-super.html

It says:

> If your semistructured or nested data is already available in either
> Apache Parquet or Apache ORC format, you can use the COPY command to
> ingest data into Amazon Redshift.
>
> The Amazon Redshift table structure should match the number of columns
> and the column data types of the Parquet or ORC files. By specifying
> SERIALIZETOJSON in the COPY command, you can load any column type in
> the file that aligns with a SUPER column in the table as SUPER. This
> includes structure and array types.
>
> COPY foo FROM 's3://bucket/somewhere'
> ...
> FORMAT PARQUET SERIALIZETOJSON;

For me, the last line

```
...
FORMAT PARQUET SERIALIZETOJSON;
```

did the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @guenhter but this did not work. However more digging into it, I found the solution as shared here by me